# Creating Radio Button dynamically

Tags: ios, objective-c, radio-button

I am want to create a dynamic radio button from the array count.If i select any one radio button other radio button should in Deselect State.
Please help me to do this .

```
   for (int f = 0; f<self.arr.count; f++) {

        UILabel *lbl = [[UILabel alloc]init];
             lbl.frame = CGRectMake(20,radio_y+10 , 30, 20);

             lbl.text = self.arr[f];
             lbl.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];


             [RadioView addSubview:lbl];

          self.yourButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5,radio_y+5 , 10, 10)];
             [self.yourButton setImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"RadioButton-Selected.png"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
             [self.yourButton setImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"RadioButton-Unselected.png"]forState: UIControlStateNormal];
             self.yourButton.selected = NO;

               [self.yourButton addTarget:self action:@selector(radioSelected:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
             [self.yourButton setTag:baseradioTag+f];

             NSLog(@"%ld",(long)self.yourButton.tag);

             [RadioView addSubview:self.yourButton];

             radio_y = radio_y +(verticalPadding+5);
                          }
  -(void)radioSelected:(UIButton*)sender {

int tag =sender.tag;
NSLog(@"buttonSelectedtag:%d",tag);

sender.selected = !sender.selected;
self.yourButton = sender;
}
```

And I did like this , but if i touch on the button ,button is not changing to selected image.

Comment: Cocoa or Cocoa Touch? Did you try anything?

Comment: please see my update code above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
-(void)radioSelected:(UIButton*)sender {

     int tag =sender.tag;
     NSLog(@"buttonSelectedtag:%d",tag);

     sender.selected = !sender.selected;
     self.yourButton = sender;

     for (UIButton *i in self.view.subviews){
          if([i isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]){
              UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)i;
              if(btn.tag == previouslySelectedTag){ //hold previouslySelectedTag, selectedTag globally 
                // Write your code. Change Button Image
              }
          }
      }
      previouslySelectedTag = sender.tag;
}
```

Comment: While i am iterating the self.view.subView only i am getting the label and scrollview.i am not getting the unbutton in that

Comment: Replace self.view with RadioView.